# Upload water mark to overlay a video via Vimeo API

Tags: php, laravel, video, vimeo, vimeo-api

I read the Videmo API and i saw that i can send videos and upload images.
But i want to send an overlay image because i will have a page with private videos and i want to show a water mark over the video, so if the user wants to buy the video i will send him the video without water mark.

And i want to send an image with sponsors to show on 3 seconds before to finish the videos like this: http://19-nacaradogol.sfo2.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/Videos/campo1/13-03-2020/18HR/v_47m31s_cam1b.mp4

All this is possible to do with Vimeo API?

Answer (score 1):

To upload a custom logo, use the endpoint documented [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/embed-presets#create_custom_logo).

You'll need an app approved for upload, and a token with `upload` scope. With that, make a `POST` request to `https://api.vimeo.com/me/customlogos` and the body sent as binary data.

The custom logo feature is documented on the Vimeo Help Center [here](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224972808-Customizing-the-embedded-player#logo).